# Dropbox HTTP API - PHP cURL added header item boundary automatically

Tags: php, curl, dropbox-api

I'm new with the Dropbox API integrations, and I'm using the PHP cURL extension to make calls to the HTTP REST API, and when I try to make a request I receive the following string:

```
Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": 
Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: 
"text/plain; boundary=----------------------------645eb1c4046b". 
Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
"text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".
```

I'm sending this with code very similar to this:

```
$sUrl = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
$oCurl = curl_init($sUrl);
$aPostData = array('path' => '', 'recursive' => true, 'show_hidden' => true);
$sBearer = "MY_TOKEN";
$aRequestOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/plain',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $sBearer),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $aPostData,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true);
curl_setopt_array($aRequestOptions);
$hExec = curl_exec($oCurl);
if ($hExec === false){
    // Some error info in JSON format
} else {
    var_dump($hExec);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it, you're doing a multipart form upload, which isn't what the API expects.

There are a few things you need to do differently:

- You should be sending up the parameters as JSON in the body.
- You should set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, accordingly.
- There isn't a `show_hidden` parameter on [/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder), but perhaps you meant to send `include_deleted`.
- The [`curl_setopt_array` method](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) takes two parameters, the first of which should be the curl handle.

Here's an updated version of your code that works for me:

```
<?php

$sUrl = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
$oCurl = curl_init($sUrl);
$aPostData = array('path' => '', 'recursive' => true, 'include_deleted' => true);
$sBearer = "MY_TOKEN";
$aRequestOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $sBearer),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($aPostData),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true);
curl_setopt_array($oCurl, $aRequestOptions);
$hExec = curl_exec($oCurl);
if ($hExec === false){
    // Some error info in JSON format
} else {
    var_dump($hExec);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, this was a code for this comment only, just adding the `json_encode` and changing the  `Content-type` header  worked.